# how can I call on a function in php file one from php file two without having to include file one inside of file two?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am writing a live chat function for a website and I have everything working except the displaying of the entered text, I can get my default statement to show up in the chat box, however I have to have the function that does this on a completely separate page here is the function

```
    if(isset($_POST['method']) === true && empty($_POST['method']) === false)
    {
        $method = trim($_POST['method']);

        if($method === 'fetch')
        {
            $messages = fetchMessages();

            if(empty($messages) === true)
            {
                echo 'A representative will be with you shortly';
            }else
            {
                foreach($messages as $message)
                {
                    $ts = $message['timestamp'];
                    ?>
                    <div class = "message">
                        <a href = "#"><?php echo date('n-j-Y h:i:s a', $ts); ?>
                        <?php echo $message['username']; ?></a>says:<p>
                        <?php echo nl2br($message['message']); ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am calling of course the `fetchMessage()` function in this file. However for the function to work I must have it in the chatRoom.php file so that I can pass the session id into it so it grabs only the chat referring to that specific session.

If I move this script to the chatRoom.php file or include the chatRoom.php file on this file the chat room breaks and shows a second copy of itself in the chat box where the chat is supposed to take place and wont do anything.

If I move fetchMessage into the file with this code I get only the default message and nothing else will display.

I am using jquery and ajax to cause an incremental fetch for the chat, which is stored in a table on my database. if you need any other information please ask I am happy to add to this and not certain what all is needed. I am still quite new to jquery and ajax.

ok here is the code for the chatRoom.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <?php
    session_start();
    include 'conection.php';

    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM chatSession WHERE user_name = '$name'";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $con) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $session = $row['session_id'];

    function fetchMessages()
    {
$get = ("SELECT * FROM chatRoom WHERE session_id = '$session' ORDER BY chat.timestamp ASC");
$hold = mysql_query($get, $con);
$show = mysql_fetch_array($hold);

return $show;
    }

    if(isset($_GET['submitmsg']))
    {
$message = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['usermsg']);
$throw = "INSERT INTO chatRoom(session_id, source, message, timestamp) VALUES('".$_GET['id']."', '".$_GET['source']."', '$message', UNIX_TIMESTAMP())";

if (!mysql_query($throw,$con))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}else
{

}
    }
    ?>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/chatStyle.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="menu">
            <p class="welcome"><b>Welcome, <?php echo $row['user_name']; ?></b></p>
            <p class="logout"><a href="nameSub.php?logout=true&name=<?php echo $row['user_name']; ?>&id=<?php echo $row['session_id']; ?>">Exit Chat</a></p>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="chatbox">
        </div>
        <form name = "message" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method = "get">
            <input type = "hidden" name = "name" value = "<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>" />
            <input name = "id" type = "hidden" value = "<?php echo $row['session_id']; ?>" />
            <input name = "source" type = "hidden" value = "<?php echo $row['user_name']; ?>" />
            <input name = "usermsg" type = "text" id = "usermsg" size = "63" />  
            <input name = "submitmsg" type = "submit"  id = "submitmsg" value = "Send" />  
        </form> 
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            fetchMessages = function()
            {
                $.ajax
                ({
                    url:'functions.php',
                    type:'post',
                    data:{method:'fetch'},
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        $('#chatbox').html(data);
                    }
                });
            }

            setInterval(fetchMessages, 5000);
            fetchMessages();
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the needed function to an external file ( eg `functions.php` ) that is included by both files.

**Edit:** elaborating more:

PHP file1:

```
 include('functions.php');
 $myvar = $_GET['myvar']; // jQuery GET variable
 $othervar = $_POST['myvar'];

 commonFunction($myvar,$othervar);
```

PHP file2:

```
include('functions.php');
 $myvar = $_GET['myvar']; // jQuery GET variable
 $othervar = $_POST['myvar'];

 commonFunction($myvar,$othervar);
```

functions.php :

```
function commonFunction($var1, $var2) { 
  // Do common proccessing here
}
```

Comment: then I run into the problem of passing the session ID into the function, which I have had no luck doing with jquery

Comment: jQuery is not involved. each PHP file does the normal processing, and calls the functions in `functions.php` and passes as a PHP parameter the processed value it received from jQuery

Comment: ok looking at your code i see where its going to hang up for me, you see the second file where I have the code I displayed above is called with jquery and nothing else, so there is no way to actually pass the variables to it unless i can find a way to do it through jquery

Comment: what you are describing is quite impossible. If both files are in PHP and are called (via any method) in such a way that they have some defined variables, they can pass them to included functions. Please elaborate if I'm not understanding something here.

Comment: give me a moment I will post the code for both files so you can see ehat is going on